# Different notation of earned value chart

Tags: burn-charts

Typically, the y axis of EV chart is the cost, the x axis is the time, and there are 3 lines plotted, one representing the planned value, the earned value and the actual value.

I have come across a different notation for such a chart, where the earned value is  represented as y axis in terms of percentage, x still representing the time, and there are two plotted lines, one for actual value and the other for planned value. Could someone please help in providing clarification on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For earned value, you can show percent or dollars on the y axis. The math is the same and will yield the same results.  The graph your describing with only the planned value and actual value using percent complete appears to be an earned schedule graph. In this case you are measuring the variance on the x axis instead of the y axis and forecasting from there.  The actual value line should be the earned value and not actual costs since the y axis is not money.